# Erro foreach codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu faço um *select* no banco de dados e exibo as imagens na página, é um portal de classificados onde a pessoa faz um anúncio e pode fazer upload de até 10 imagens.

Até ai está tudo bem, eu pego o anúncio e ele é exibido na página, o problema que ele está exibindo o anúncio a mesma quantidade de vezes que ele teve de upload de imagem.

Se o anúncio tiver 5 fotos é exibido 5 vezes, se ele tiver uma exibe uma vez.
O que posso fazer para ele imprimir só o primeiro item do *array*?

```php
class Carroshome extends CI_Model
{
    public function exibeCarrosHome($limit =0,$offset =0){

        if ($limit > 0)  $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("anuncios");
        $this->db->join("fotosanuncios", "anuncios.id = fotosanuncios.idPost");
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');

        return $valida = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

    public function totalLinhas(){
        return $this->db->count_all("anuncios");
    }
}
```

---

Meu foreach está assim.

```
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6 carrosRetangulo">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12 carrosBanner">
                <div class="fundoFoto">

                    <a href="<?= base_url("car/$dado[id]") ?>" style="padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; border:none !important;background: transparent !important;">
                        <img src="<?= base_url("$dado[caminho]thumb/$dado[thumb]") ?>" class="carrosFotomini" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="detalhesCarro">
                    <ul class="itensCarroFront">
                    <li>Model : <?= substr($dado['modelo'],0,15) ?></li>
                        <li>State     : <?= $dado['stateAuto'] ?></li>
                        <li>Year      : <?= $dado['year'] ?></li>
                        <li>Miles     : <?= $dado['odometer'] ?></li>
                        <li>Fuel      : <?= $dado['fuel'] ?></li>
                        <li>Transmission : <?= $dado['transmission'] ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="precoCarro"><span class="precoVertical"><?=  ($dado['price'])? numeroEmReais($dado['price']) : "check" ?></span></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Resolvido com ajuda do Jonathan

public function puxaThumb($id){
        $this->db->where("idPost",$id);
        return $this->db->get("fotosanuncios")->row_array();

```
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruno, o que está acontecendo é que ao dar o join com a tabela 'fotosanuncios' o registro principal, que é o do carro, acaba sendo replicado pela quantidade de registros existentes na tabela 'fotosanuncios'.

**SUGESTÃO #1**

Não faça o join com a tabela de fotos, adicione uma nova chave no array retornado pela consulta, por exemplo $valida['fotos']. Então alimente essa chave com o resultado de uma busca independente na tabela 'fotosanuncios'.

Rode um foreach para recuperar as imagens para cada resultado da busca principal e então recupere as imagens de cada registro.

**SUGESTÃO #2**

Crie um model para 'fotosanuncios' (caso não tenha) e adicione nele um método que retorna um array com as imagens para cada carro. Chame esse método no foreach da sugestão #1, em substituição à query explícita. Assim você não precisa executar uma consulta a outra tabela no controller 'CarrosHome', e mantém o seu código mais organizado.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Jonathan, entendi oque devo fazer, vou criar uma função recebendo um $id e ele faz um selec da primeira linha que encontrar no banco.

Muito obrigado, não sei como não pensei nisso antes, eu estou trabalhando muitas hrs por dia neste projeto e acho que estou bugando Rs.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.

Segue código do model.

public function puxaThumb($id){
  $this->db->where("idPost",$id);
  return $this->db->get("fotosanuncios")->row_array();

 }